# Bad Indentation of OCaml Comments in vim

Tags: vim, ocaml, auto-indent

I use ocamldoc-style comment, but vim is annoying me because it indents the comment when it should not.

For instance, with the following code:

```
(**
 * {[
```

If I open a new line when being of the second line of the above code, vim will indent the code so it will look like:

```
(**
 * {[
     *
```

So I need to remove 4 spaces everytime.

I tried using `ocp-indent`, but the result is the same.

What can I do to not have the four additional spaces when I open a new line in a ocamldoc comment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can get the desired behavior by editing the ocaml indent file.

I updated the line 208:

```
if lline =~ '\(:\|=\|->\|<-\|(\|\[\|{\|{<\|\[|\|\[<\|\<\(begin\|do\|else\|fun\|function\|functor\|if\|initializer\|object\|parser\|private\|sig\|struct\|then\|try\)\|\<object\s*(.*)\)\s*$'
```

to:

```
 if lline =~ '\(:\|=\|->\|<-\|(\|{\|{<\|\[|\|\[<\|\<\(begin\|do\|else\|fun\|function\|functor\|if\|initializer\|object\|parser\|private\|sig\|struct\|then\|try\)\|\<object\s*(.*)\)\s*$'
```

(I removed the `\[` pattern from this regular expression.)

This change has the effect of not indenting after a `[` outside of the comment as well, but I don't mind this side effect.

I'll let this question opened a few days to see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Leading stars in comments are not idiomatic at all in OCaml (and badly handled by ocamldoc), just drop the stars.

The behavior you observed is probably to be expected. Most indentation engine try to indent the code in comments, and `{[` is the start of a code block which explains the indentation.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure this indentation is always expected, since the same happens if I type `(` instead of `{[` and `(` does not seem to have any meaning in `ocamldoc`. And by the way, `ocamldoc` has the `-stars` option to support this formatting.